# Xamarin.Android APK Deployment failed - INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK base.apk code is missing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

My Xamarin.Android app can no longer be deployed to an emulator/device. I can compile it successfully and the deployment process is started but in the end it fails. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin.Android:

> [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in
>   /data/app/my.app.bundle.id-agudyKm4Ib_8OheG3_5zmg==: Package
>   /data/app/my.app.bundle.id-agudyKm4Ib_8OheG3_5zmg==/base.apk code is
>   missing]

My build configuration is below:

- Multi-dex = ON because without it I'm getting the DEX size error
- DEX compiler = DX (D8 doesn't work, I'm getting a compilation error that some classes are missing, see below)
- Code shrinker = Off (this is a debug build to run on local emulator/device)

This error occurs if I set DEX compiler to D8:

```
R8 : warning : Missing class: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText (and 10 more similar errors)
missing R8 : error : Compilation can't be completed because some library classes are missing.
```

The error occurs with all the settings above, this is basically the only configuration I can build my app but unable to deploy it to device:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:  Deployment failed
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/my.app.bundle.id-agudyKm4Ib_8OheG3_5zmg==: Package /data/app/my.app.bundle.id-agudyKm4Ib_8OheG3_5zmg==/base.apk code is missing]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00152] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:341 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<InstallPackage>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:753 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <f9d1b832704f410aa8ec771f4fe80552>:0 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00189] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:187 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003df] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:203 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.InstallPackage () [0x003be] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:433 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003ae] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:217 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunLoggedAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0002f] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:119
```

Comment: Try to disable Multidex, and settings Dextool to D8 instead of dx.

Comment: Multi-dex = ON because without it I'm getting the DEX size error, DEX compiler = DX (D8 doesn't work, I'm getting a compilation error that some classes are missing, see below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a Xamarin expert but if you can see the native files, can you check gradle.properties if it has:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Also inside the build.gradle of the native files (app directory) you should have:

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, there is no gradle but I will definitely try to figure out how to that with xamarin tools!

Comment: I was able to complete the migration to AndroidX, it required a few steps but basically I was able to use D8 once AndroidX support was added.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the I wasn't able to make it work with `DEX Compiler` = `DX`, and when you switch to `D8`, the migration to `AndroidX` is required. In terms of `Xamarin`, you have to add the following package and all additional requested dependencies:

```
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
  </PackageReference>
```

Another issue I hit was the usage of old packages.config file which have to be migrated to the project `PackageReference`. This is not supported from `Visual Studio for Mac` so you have to switch to `Windows` to accomplish that tasks. A lot of extra steps just to compile an application in support.